# Tkinter: is there something such as askopendirectories?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm developing an application that runs a script to archive a bunch of files. The user input is handled with a browse button with a `askopenfilenames` function attached to it (using tkFileDialog). All this works fine, but it only adds files, not folders. How can I make it so that the user can select both files **and** folders?

I haven't been able to find a 'open..' function that handles this. Nor have I been able to find one that opens multiple directories. The only way to solve this that I can think of is select one folder and get all of its contents. But this solution fails if there are files in the folder that aren't meant to be archived which isn't very user friendly.

Is there any other way that I can handle this?